# Processing array of values at cell location across raster maps using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, array

I have several (say n=10) raster maps with ratings values. At a particular cell location, I would like to create a sum composed of the maximum rating, half the next highest rating, then a quarter of the next highest, etc.

I understand how to find the MAX, MIN, AVERAGE ... across maps, but not how to order the values at a cell location to process them.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Suggestions?

Comment: It's ugly, but you could mask the max out with a `Con`, and save the max of that to alt1, then repeat for alt2; then it's just a math expression of `max+alt1/2+alt2/4`

Comment: Just sample it and work with output.